# Calculate transformation matrix of 3d plane given 4 corners

Tags: matrix, 3d, linear-algebra, transformation

I have a 3d plane at the world origin that is aligned with the world X/Y plane (facing the Z axis). I then have four 3d vertex positions for a new plane transformed into some location in 3d space.

Both planes have the same winding order for all 4 vertices.

I have a guarantee that the 4 corners are planar and there is no skewing (the plane may have still been scaled individually on the x/y axes).

How can I create a 4x4 transformation matrix given the final 4 corners of this plane?

Comment: So the original plane is also defined by 4 corners? And are these also unskewed?

Comment: Yes, the original plane is always located at the origin (0,0,0), with corners at 

(-0.5, -0.5), 
(0.5, -0.5), 
(-0.5, 0.5),
(0.5, 0.5) (on the world X/Y plane)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics instead of programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that the plane looks like this:

[image]

Construct a "local basis" of the plane, with the:

- X-axis parallel to AD / BC
- Y-axis parallel to AB / CD
- Z-axis parallel to the normal
- Origin O at the center of the quad

[image]

The transformation matrix can be decomposed into **3** components:

---

**1 – Scale**

Since the original quad has dimensions of 1x1 units, the scaling factor along the X and Y local axes are simply the side lengths, i.e. the lengths of AD and AB respectively. Ignore the Z scaling factor since the quad is planar.

Therefore the scaling component is given by:

[image]

---

**2 - Rotation**

The rotational component can be directly constructed from the local basis axes X, Y, Z; each vector (normalized) is the corresponding column of the matrix.

[image]

Therefore the rotational component is given by:

[image]

---

**3 - Translation**

This is the easiest one; the translation vector is simply the absolute coordinate of the quad's center O, and is equal to the last column of the matrix.

[image]

Therefore the translational component is given by:

[image]

---

> The final matrix can be obtained by multiplying the above in the following order:
>
> [image]
>
> i.e. the components are applied in the order **1** ⇨ **2** ⇨ **3**.